# Stacking images within a table

Tags: html, css

I have just started to learn basic HTML/CSS via Dreamweaver.

It is a reasonably simple issue (I think).

I have two images within a table.

The images are responsive to change size. However,(and I have done this before but can't remember how) - How do I get one image to stack one above the other; once the screen resolution drops to a smaller size?

Here is the code:

[image: code]

Comment: please, paste here actual code instead of code image, also, provide us with the actual view you want to create.

Comment: Aside from the setup of you question, as mentioned above, the fact that each image is inside its own `<td>` element on the same row means they'll always be on the same line. Have you considered putting them within the same `<td>` element or perhaps using something other than a table? If the table is purely to display the images then `<div>` would be a much better solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] (a picture of code does not count)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you have two images next to eachother, and when the screen gets small they have to be one above the other. You can do this by CSS Media queries. First you have the images next to eachother. So they are probably like `width: 50%`. But what you can do is add the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 500px)` and inside that query you can set the images to `width: 100%`. Look at the link below for more information about media queries:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
img {
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```